# Google Docs создание скриптов в электронных таблицах

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Недавно начал "изучать" google docs и возник вопрос написания скриптов к электронным таблицам, есть ли гдето материалы, как их писать с нуля для начинающих, т.к. много понаходил, но пока не разбирусь. В экселе на vba делал... тут както всё не так...
Если есть у кого ссылка на русскоязычные ресурсы, напишите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вопрос должен быть как всеобъемлящий, неконкретный и призывающий к бесконечному обсуждению. Ответ Александра Иванова следует перевести в описание тэга [tag:google-apps-script]

Answer (score 2):

Я сам только начал скриптовать в Гугл. Пользуюсь:
[По американски](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)
По русски: [Скрипты](https://plus.google.com/communities/110878650918085680190), [документы](https://plus.google.com/communities/110105258652966548522). Если покричать народ поможет.

Answer (score 1):

## Введение

Сравнивать VBA, скрипты LO и Google Apps Script не верно. Говорить о "google docs" - все равно, что говорить ни о чем. Писать "скрипт в Google Spreadsheet" - это просто написать, что одно приложение сервиса связано с другим.

Не мне, правда, учить, что к чему, но некоторые вещи очевидны. Некоторые из них, хоть и косвенно относятся к вопросу и отображены здесь [НАИМЕНОВАНИЕ ПРИЛОЖЕНИЙ СЕРВИСА "ДИСК GOOGLE"](http://gdriveru.blogspot.com/2014/11/drivenames.html)

Далее предлагаю рассмотреть занимательный файл [1. Google Apps Script. Начало. Нужны они вам или нет?](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1h9OISgBtupWSwcz9Nz_GXJTwO2o6bSpyk3muEvQRYSc/edit?usp=sharing)

## Ссылки

### Официальные. Английский язык

#### Документация

Вся основная документация, разжеванная до состояния готового к употреблению пюре, находится на официальном ресурсе [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)

#### Блог разработчика

[Google Apps Developer Blog](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/search/label/Apps%20Script) по моему скромному мнению является достойнейшим ресурсом.

#### Сообщества

Три лидирующих сообщества по скриптам, конечно же на G+

- [Google Apps Script](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769) уже упоминалось выше, является ключевым, читают сами разработчики скриптов.
- [Developing add-ons for Google Docs/Sheets/Forms](https://plus.google.com/communities/117193953428311185494) полуофициальное сообщество поддержки разработчиков аддонов.
- [Google Docs and Drive](https://plus.google.com/communities/102220963265544691087) полуофициальное сообщество по Диску, где вас непременно направят куда надо.

#### Форумы

Давным-давно была группа по скриптам, но ее закрыли в пользу **stackoverflow**, по тэгу [[google-apps-script]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)

### Неофициальные. Английский язык

- [google script examples](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/)
- [ramblings.mcpher.com](http://ramblings.mcpher.com/)

Почтенные и достойные мужи управляют этими ресурсами.

### Неофициальные. Русский язык

#### Сообщества

- [Google Документы и Диск](https://plus.google.com/communities/110105258652966548522) раздел Google Apps Script
- [Google Apps. Russian](https://plus.google.com/communities/110878650918085680190) если у вас корпоративный аккаунт или приложение выходит за рамки Диска
- [GDG Russian Speaking Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/111363131138208606444) GDG Россия - собрание разработчиков (любые вопросы)

#### Чаты

Есть дружелюбный хэнгаут по Google Apps на русском языке. Обращайтесь в личку.

## Литература

Литература по Google Apps Script устаревает очень быстро. Необходимо знать JavaScript, поэтому и литературу лучше подбирать соответствующую.

## По существу

Если вам необходимо написать скрипт именно для Таблицы, то он ничем не будет отличаться от скрипта для Документа или Формы. Поэтому вернее задавать вопрос напрямик: "Я делаю так-то так-то, хочу то-то то-то, как сделать?".

Answer (score 0):

Есть хороший [пример работы](http://findevelop.blogspot.com/2012/05/google-spreadsheet.html) со скриптами в Google Spreadsheet. Для первоначального освоения инструмента должно хватить. Более подробное описание и примеры есть [тут](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_writing_scripts)